# Best way to copy file from File Share?

Tags: c#

Already i posted my earlier question about my FTP process (simple and short ),it will check the ftp server directory and match the files and download it,am trying to do the same thing using file share but little bit more logical way.

Scenairo like this ,my db tell my file name (e.g text.exe) and the location (Detroit) based on the location (i have config file ,eg Detroit Value ://10.26.10.127/testfolder, Washington Value://10.26.10.127/testfolder).

then i will copy text.exe from (//10.26.10.127/testfolder) to my local drive.

Step 1:Get the file list from FileShare
Step 2:store the filename in the stringbuilder
step 3:use the condition (contains) to match the file name
Step 4: Copy from fileshare location to local location.

Please someone advise me where to start ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but it sounds like you're looking for [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx).

Comment: what is the size range? are they(or might they be) huge fiels?

Comment: @AnarchistGeek,yep some of them are around 450meg to 17Gig files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it starting from the data.

```
System.Data.DataTable dt; //Fill your data into this datatable

string destPath = "Drive:\\Your_destination_path";
string fullSrcPath = null;

foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
    fullSrcPath = dr["PathColName"].ToString() + "\\" + dr["fileColName"].ToString();
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(fullSrcPath)){
        System.IO.File.Copy(fullSrcPath,destPath+ "\\"+dr["fileColName"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I might explain little bit more about my scenario,the answer you provide might not suits my scenario,for example am getting the file name details from db(thru wcf) so i got the file name : "TestXYZ " then i used your System.IO.File.Copy(fullSrcPath,destPath+ "\\"+dr["fileColName"].ToString());

Comment: to copy all the file who have the file name,for my destination location (//10.120.10.126) have file like TestXYZ.exe,TestXYZ.txt,TestXYZ.bak,Test.exe" in that case i will copy all the file except test.exe. so i have to use get list files in the directory first then check the file is matched with my file name then use file.copy to copy in to local. is that make sense.